# Change parameter value in EXEC function in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure where I insert a product like this:

```
BEGIN TRY
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    INSERT INTO Product.ProductDetail VALUES (@ProductId,@IsDeleted);
    return 1;
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
INSERT INTO Exception.SqlTransaction VALUES ('usp_AddProduct', ERROR_NUMBER(), ERROR_SEVERITY(), ERROR_STATE(),  ERROR_PROCEDURE(), ERROR_LINE(),
ERROR_MESSAGE())
    return 0

    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

As you see I insert in Exception.SqlTransactions name of sp and sql error codes. That I want to do is to create another sp with that insert and use `EXEC`, how can I send name of sp?

First I create `sqlErrorCodes` SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SQLErrorCodes 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @sp_Name varchar(max) 

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
INSERT INTO Exception.SqlTransaction VALUES (@sp_Name, ERROR_NUMBER(), ERROR_SEVERITY(), ERROR_STATE(),  ERROR_PROCEDURE(), ERROR_LINE(),
ERROR_MESSAGE())
END
GO
```

Then into original sp I change this line

```
INSERT INTO Exception.SqlTransaction VALUES ('usp_AddProduct', ERROR_NUMBER(), ERROR_SEVERITY(), ERROR_STATE(),  ERROR_PROCEDURE(), ERROR_LINE(),
    ERROR_MESSAGE())
```

And now I use :

```
EXEC SQLErrorCodes('usp_AddProduct')
```

but I get:

> Incorrect syntax near 'usp_AddProduct'.

what am I doing wrong?. How can I change parameter value @sp_Name when I use `EXEC` sentence into another sp? Regards

---

**update:**

As Alex comments I change sp to:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SQLErrorCodes] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @sp_Name varchar(max), 
    @ErrorNumber varchar(max) = ERROR_NUMBER,
    @ErrorSeverity varchar(max) = ERROR_SEVERITY,
    @ErrorState varchar (max) = ERROR_STATE,
    @ErrorProcedure varchar (max) = ERROR_PROCEDURE ,
    @ErrorLine varchar(max) = ERROR_LINE,
    @ErrorMessage varchar(max) = ERROR_MESSAGE
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
INSERT INTO Exception.SqlTransaction VALUES (@sp_Name, @ErrorNumber, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState,  @ErrorProcedure, @ErrorLine,
@ErrorMessage)
```

Now how should be I call in original sp with EXEC?

Comment: what do you mean? I will pass as parameters in SQLErrorCodes sp? can you explain me more please? @Alex

Comment: can you see my update @Alex ?

Comment: please disregard my previous comments re SP parameters.

Answer (score 2):

should be without brackets

```
EXEC SQLErrorCodes 'usp_AddProduct'
```